# Reflection Field Accessor, get property value

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reflection, properties

I have a class Human and need to get "IsChecked" value. ItemsSource may have different types, but all classes has IsChecked property.

```
public class Human{
    public bool IsChecked{
      get;
      set;
    }
}

private void CheckBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //sender is CheckBox
    //How set value from IsChecked?
    var prop = t.GetType().GetProperties().Single(n => n.Name == "IsChecked");//I can access it by this method, but can't set value of sender which CheckBox;
}
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit.  You don't put the answer in the question.  If you have an answer, post it as an answer.  Otherwise, accept a user's answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that for some reason you can't refactor your `Human` class to implement some `ICheckable` interface, containing `IsChecked`, right?

If you're using C# 4.0, an alternative is to use the `dynamic` data type, which will allow you to set a property only checked at runtime:

```
private void CheckBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
     dynamic dynamicObject  = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag;
     bool checkedState = dynamicObject.IsChecked;
}
```

And if all else fails and you really have to use reflection, you're 90% of the way there. You just need to call the `PropertyInfo` object's `GetValue` method, giving it the instance you wish to retrieve the value from:

```
PropertyInfo prop = t.GetType().GetProperty("IsChecked"); // Simpler.
var isChecked = prop.GetValue(t, null);
(sender as CheckBox).IsChecked = isChecked;
```

Comment: prop.SetValue(t, true, null); //Sets value Checked for all checbox in context, but how to retrieve it from sender? Sender.Tag contains class which have IsChecked property

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you want to SET the value. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I want to get value from sender.Tag and set IsChecked to CheckBox.

Comment: I was using the `t` you were using in the OP, but I changed it again, now that I understood you're trying to get the Tag property from the `sender`.

Comment: OP is "original post", your original question. What is unclear right now?

Comment: var prop = t.GetType().GetProperties().Single(n => n.Name == "IsChecked");
var tag = ((sender as CheckBox).Tag as JumpListItem).DataContext;// I get IsChecked property from class, now how to apply this property to CheckBox(sender) IsChecked property?

Comment: You're mixing two different issues here, which makes it hard to answer your question. See the latest version of the answer. 1) Use prop.GetValue to get the IsChecked value from your Human object. 2) Cast the `sender` to a `CheckBox` so you can access its `IsChecked` property.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest refactoring it to use a base class or at least an interface. But, if that's not possible, simlply using *dynamic* can do the trick:

```
dynamic obj = t;
bool value = t.IsChecked;
```

Comment: Dynamics are not supported on Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

This would toggle state:

```
private void CheckBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var prop = e.GetType().GetProperty("IsChecked", 
                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        // read the current value
        var current = (bool)prop.GetValue(sender, null);
        //and toggle it
        prop.SetValue(sender, !current, null);
}
```

Though refactoring to a base/interface would probably be cleaner, and certainly perform better.  If it's always a CheckBox, then this would be the simple route too:

```
private void CheckBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var c = sender as CheckBox;
        // read the current value
        var current = c.IsChecked;
        //and toggle it
        c.IsChecked = !current;
}
```